# How to access params in the callback of a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activemodel

I have a callback of a model that needs to create a dependent object based on another field entered in the form. But `params` is undefined in the callback method. Is there another way to access it? What's the proper way to pass a callback method parameters from a form?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :enrollments

  after_create :create_enrollment_log
  private
  def create_enrollment_log
    enrollments.create!(status: 'signed up', started: params[:sign_up_date])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

**params are not accessible in models, even if you pass them as a parameter then it would be consider as bad practice and might also be dangerous.**

What you can do is to create virtual attribute and use it in your model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, :sign_up_date
 has_many :enrollments

 after_create :create_enrollment_log
 private
 def create_enrollment_log
   enrollments.create!(status: 'signed up', started: sign_up_date)
 end
end
```

Where sign_up_date is your virtual attribute

Comment: This wouldn't conflict with the database?

Comment: not at all unless you have an attribute of same name in database i would suggest you to have look at this rails cast http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes

Comment: I get the following error: `undefined method `sign_up_date' for #<User:0x007fcd17888bc8>` when trying to assign it. Which does seem odd as without querying the database, it looks just like the `name` field which I have no problem assigning. Does Rails query the database upon `.new` or from a `date_select` form helper?

Answer (score 2):

params will not be available inside the models.

One possible way to do this would be to define a virtual attribute in the user model and use that in the callback

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name,:sign_up_date
 has_many :enrollments

 after_create :create_enrollment_log
 private
 def create_enrollment_log
   enrollments.create!(status: 'signed up', started: sign_up_date)
 end
end
```

you will have to make sure that the name of the field in the form is user[:sign_up_date]

Comment: wouldn't this try to save it to the database as well, where the sign_up_date user field doesn't exist?

Comment: nope, unless there is a matching column in the users table it can not save it to the database

Comment: I get `undefined method `sign_up_date' for #<User:0x007fcd17888bc8>` when using `date_select` in my form. Or I get `undefined method `sign_up_date=' for #<User:0x007fcd124609d8>` if I try to do a simple assignment to it in my controller.

Comment: A virtual attribute shoud be 'attr_accessor' but not attr_accessible! These two things are totally different!