# Using Parameter in Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a validation that needs to apply only per a certain project that a user is in. The solution I came up with is to call this model method from the controller:

**controller:**

```
Client.validate_uniq_record(params[:project_id])
```

**model:**

```
def self.validate_uniq_record(proj_id)
    validates_uniqueness_of :item, scope: :price, conditions: -> {where(project_id: proj_id)}
end
```

From reading other questions, it looks like passing a param to a model is a big nono:
[How to access params in the callback of a Rails model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612846/how-to-access-params-in-the-callback-of-a-rails-model) I could not figure out how to do this through a virtual attribute either.

How would I `validates_uniqueness_of` for only the current project the user is in?

Note, the `Client` object has a `project_id` column as an FK

Comment: You would usually use an association and use validates with the scope option pointing to the foreign key in conjunction with a compound index in the DB.

Comment: yep! just setting the scope to project_id and calling the validation in the model without a method worked perfectly. Do you want to post this as an answer and I'll accept?